# npm install says cannot find file

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, node-modules, babeljs

I am cloning a repo and get the following error when running `npm install`

> > ENOENT:no such file or directory, rename '/Users/waston/Desktop/hm/STEMuli_MaterialUI/node_modules/.staging/client-6b05b6f7/node_modules/@babel/helper-module-imports' -> '/Users/waston/Desktop/hm/STEMuli_MaterialUI/node_modules/.staging/@babel/helper-module-imports-b86e8d76'

I thought maybe if I do `npm install --save-dev @babel/helper-module-imports` that may fix it, but even doing that gives me the same error.

**package.json(server)**

```
    "dependencies": {
        "azure-storage": "^2.10.2",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "cd": "^0.3.3",
        "client": "file:client",
        "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
        "install": "^0.12.2",
        "into-stream": "^4.0.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.0.12",
        "multer": "^1.4.1",
        "multer-azure-storage": "^0.2.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
        "npm": "^6.4.1",
        "passport": "^0.4.0",
        "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
        "validator": "^9.4.1"
      },
 "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  }
```

**Client package.json**
"

```
dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@material-ui/core": "1.5.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "2.0.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.11",
    "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
    "ajv": "6.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "blueimp-file-upload": "^9.22.0",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "cloudinary-jquery-file-upload": "^2.5.0",
    "cloudinary-react": "^1.0.6",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.0.0",
    "fullcalendar-reactwrapper": "^1.0.7",
    "fullcalendar-reactwrapper-scheduler": "^1.0.7",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "1.3.3",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.3",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.19.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "4.4.1",
    "react-chartist": "0.13.1",
    "react-chat-widget": "^2.1.4-1",
    "react-datetime": "2.15.0",
    "react-dnd": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-file-viewer": "^0.5.0",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "react-icons": "^3.0.5",
    "react-jvectormap": "0.0.3",
    "react-material-icons": "^1.0.3",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-nouislider": "2.0.1",
    "react-parallax": "^2.0.0",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^2.2.14",
    "react-player": "^1.6.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-select": "^2.1.1",
    "react-slick": "0.23.1",
    "react-stepzilla": "^4.8.0",
    "react-svg-icons": "^0.3.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.12.16",
    "react-table": "6.8.6",
    "react-tagsinput": "3.19.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "video-react": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-import-rename": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "prettier": "^1.13.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "build-package-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/materialComponents/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss dist/material-kit-react.css",
    "build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist",
    "deploy": "npm run build"
  },
```

Comment: can you try rm -rf node_modules && npm install again ?

Comment: @HarshShah, Just tried it got the same thing.

Comment: can you try to change babel/runtime version ?

Comment: Do you mean by doing `npm install --save @babel/runtime`? If so I just tried it and same thing.

Comment: also you can do one thing delete package-lock.json and then delete npm_modules and run command npm cache clean and then run $ npm install

Comment: @HarshShah I'm not ignoring the answering I will have to try this when I get home. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Delete your package-lock.json and the node_modules folder, then run `npm install`

Comment: I'm not ignoring the answering I will have to try this when I get home. Thank you!

Comment: It was deleting package-logk.json that helped me out, when just deleting node_modules did not.